# apache cassandra SSL using public certificate authority?

Tags: cassandra, openssl, ssl-certificate, keystore, datastax

I am trying to establish node to node encryption. I am following datastax online guidance available for ssl encryption on below link- https://docs.datastax.com/en/security/5.1/security/secSetUpSSLCert.html
as per the documentation i have skipped first two steps and followed from step-3.

so, I have created the keystore, using below command-

```
keytool -genkeypair -keyalg RSA -alias node1 -keystore cassandra.jks -storepass cass123 -keypass cass123 -validity 365 -keysize 2048 -dname "CN=host1, OU=cluster1, O=org, C=US"
```

after creating the keystore, here the public certificate authority have two level of encryption or certs. first is root.cert and another is intermediate.cert.
when i have checked through below command, intermediate.cert is signed or verifyed by root.cert.

```
openssl verify -CAfile root.cert intermediate.cert , Got OK in Response.
```

after than with keystore(cassandra.jks), i have raise the certificate signed request (CSR):

```
 keytool -keystore cassandra.jks -alias node1 -certreq -file cassandra.csr -keypass cass123 -storepass cass123 -dname "CN=host1, OU=cluster1, O=org, C=US"
```

then after uploading this CSR file (cassandra.csr) to public certificate authority i got in response one Cert.cer file.

so, then i checked whether the Cert.cer file get signed by root.cert or not.

```
openssl verify -CAfile root.cert Cert.cer
```

Got unable to load certificate in Response, with error message-

```
140044398696338:error:0906D06C:PEM routines:PEM_read_bio:no start line:pem_lib.c707:Expecting TRUSTED CERTIFICATE
```

Even I have Checked the Cert.cer with intermediate.cert-- got the same above error message.

Is this mean the Cert.cer which i got in response to csr request in not properly signed by certificate authority.

So i have stopped further steps here, which needed for cassandra ssl implementation.

Please, let me know, if i miss something or doing in wrong manner. much appreciated all help and suggestions

Comment: please use instructions from DSE 6.7: https://docs.datastax.com/en/security/6.7/security/secSslTOC.html - they should work with older versions as well

Comment: @Alex, I have edited the questions, with the specified documents also getting the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue is resolved, due to platform issue certs generated have extras carriage characters ^M. after removing this and merging root and intermediate certs together it works fine.